# If you are layed-off by the US Navy, do you lose retirements benefits?

Tags: united-states, retirement, pension

Sailors in the United States Navy get a pension after 20 years of service.

A few days ago, I met a man who told me he had been laid-off from the US Navy after 17 years of service and that he now works as the manager of a pizza shop, does this mean he won't be receiving any pension?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about personal finance but rather about labor law and employment contracts. Workplace@SE maybe?

Comment: @littleadv I think this question can be generalized, and the obvious misinformation/FUD removed. IMHO, the essential question is: "Can you lose 100% of your retirement pension benefits if you are terminated before retirement?" I would imagine there are U.S. laws that protect earned pension credits after a minimum period. The answer to this kind of question/FUD is of interest to individuals who participate in workplace/public sector defined benefit pension plans.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea that may be, but it will still be off topic. As I said, workplace@se is more suitable for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 2):

The US military has addressed this issue via the [Temporary Early Retirement Authority](http://myarmybenefits.us.army.mil/Home/Benefit_Library/Federal_Benefits_Page/Temporary_Early_Retirement_Authority_%28TERA%29.html?serv=147). This example applies to the US Army but it should also exist for the Navy.

> The FY 2012 National Defense Authorization Act (NDAA), Public Law
>   112-81, enacted 31 December 2011, authorized the military services to
>   offer early retirement to Soldiers who have completed at least 15
>   years of active service. This is a discretionary authority and not an
>   entitlement. The Army has elected to use this limited program as part
>   of a comprehensive force management strategy to shape the force. It
>   does not apply to Soldiers of the Army National Guard or the U.S. Army
>   Reserve.
>
> **Eligibility**:
>
> Early retirement under TERA is limited to active duty Regular Army
>   Soldiers who are denied continued active duty service with an
>   established involuntary separation date of 30 September 2018 or
>   earlier who meet the following criteria:
>
> a. Noncommissioned Officers (NCOs) denied continued service as a result of an approved Qualitative Service Program (QSP)
>   centralized selection board who are serving on active duty and have
>   completed 15 but less than 20 years of active service as of the
>   established involuntary separation date.
>
> b. Officers/Warrant Officers who have twice failed selection for promotion to the next grade, including those who have
>   been selected for, but not yet accepted, selective continuation, who
>   are serving on active duty and have 15 but less than 20 years of
>   active service as of their established involuntary separation date.
>
> c. All Soldiers must meet all eligibility requirements for retirement for length of service for a 20-year retirement, except as
>   provided for under the TERA program.  Exceptions to other eligibility
>   requirements are not considered.  In all cases, early retirement will
>   not occur prior to attainment of 15 years of service on the
>   established separation date.
>
> This early retirement benefit will not be extended to Soldiers who:
>
> a. Were previously separated under Voluntary Separation Incentive (VSI), Special Separation Benefit (SSB), or Voluntary
>   Separation Pay (VSP) programs.
>
> b. Are under evaluation for disability retirement under Title 10, Chapter 61.
>
> c. Are members of the Army National Guard or U.S. Army Reserves.